# c# help using system.uri functions

Tags: c#

i have a STRING in C# with a long url such as:
http://mysite.com/testing/testingPages/area/ten/p1.aspx

how can i use system.uri class to get the http://mysite.com part only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uri myURI = new Uri("http://mysite.com/testing/testingPages/area/ten/p1.aspx");
```

`myURI.Host` gets the domain or do whatever you want with the `myURI` object

Answer (score 1):

I believe [`Uri.GetLeftPart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart.aspx) is what you're after:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "http://mysite.com/testing/testingPages/area/ten/p1.aspx";
        Uri uri = new Uri(text);
        // Prints http://mysite.com
        Console.WriteLine(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically get the part up to the domain (including scheme, username, password, and port), then you would call the [GetLeftPart method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart.aspx) on the Uri class like so:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://mysite.com/testing/testingPages/area/ten/p1.aspx");
string baseUri = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```